# I can't seem to figure out why my read/write to a file functions are not working

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, fwrite, fread

I've been doing my project and the last thing I need to do is to save to and start reading a structure array from a file on startup of the program, but I can't figure out why the code isn't loading the information of the file. I know that it does save something since I can open the .dat file and read it in a text editor.
I apologize for the terrible style, but I'm still new. That's a sample of just that function in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

struct property {
    int num;
    char nBrok[50];
    char type[10];
    string adress;
    char outlook[20];
    double price;
    double size;
    int nRooms;
    int floor;
    int status;
};
fstream fp;

void fileWrite(property bDanni[], int n) {
    fp.open("dbase.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
    if (!fp) {
        cout << "\n Error in file \n"; exit(1);
    }
    fp.write((char*)bDanni, sizeof(property) *n);
    fp.close();
}

int fileRead(property bDanni[]) {
    long pos; int n = 0, i; property b;
    fp.open("dbase.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    if (!fp) {
        cout << "\n file does not exist\n"; return n;
    }
    fp.seekg(0l, ios::end);
    pos = fp.tellg();
    fp.close();
    n = pos / (sizeof(property));
    fp.open("dbase.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    if (!fp) {
        cout << "\n Error in file \n"; exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fp.read((char*)&b, sizeof(property));
        bDanni[i] = b;
    }
    fp.close();
    return n;
}
int main() {
    property bDanni[100];
    char answer;
    int total = 0;
    cout << "Do you wat to read from the save file?(y/n): ";
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == 'y') {
      int total = fileRead(bDanni);
    }
}
```

Comment: `property` contains an `std::string` which cannot be persisted the way you're trying.  You'll have to write serialization functions that know how to deal with non-trivial types (e.g., `std::string`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a C++ `std::string` is much more complex than a char array. The implementation is not mandated by the standard, but in common implementation, the `string` element contains a pointer to a character array. That means that your code only stores into the file a pointer value instead of a character string.

In C++ idiom, the `std::string` type is said not to be *trivially copyable*. And the `fread`-`fwrite` method can only be used with trivially copyable types.

That means that you will have to use *serialization* to replace the raw byte  representation of a `std::string` with a sequence of bytes that represent the *useful content* of the object, something that you will be able to use at read time to construct back the object. Not really complex but beyond a mere `fwrite`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into serialization and try and figure out how I'm gonna have to implement it in my program. Stay safe.